# How to make Selenium driver.get with Scrapy faster

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is a python script that is intended to *monitor a certain website, and as soon as there's any change to a particular class(in this example* `'.ant-card-body'`*), do something*.

However, `driver.get()` takes about 14 seconds to fully load the webpage...

**Could you help me what kind of workaround I could use to make it faster, to detect element change instantly?**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy
import time

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic"
    allowed_domains = [""]
    start_urls = ['https://solanamonkeysclub.com/#/#mint']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # constantly get webpage and check if an element has been changed
        while True:
            start = time.time()
            self.driver.get(response.url)
            end = time.time()
            print(end - start)   # takes 14 SECONDS...

            new_elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ant-card-body')
            for new_elem in new_elems:
                print(f'{"new_elem":10} : {new_elem.text}')
                if new_elem.text != 0:
                    pass

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(BasicSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Selenium with scrapy is super fast in the context of headless/ automation  world.

Comment: Fazlul, thanks for the info! I tried with `Scrapy` but it still seems to take quite a while to load ... (edited post)

Comment: selenium with bs4 takes 20 second and  it takes 14  a bit firster. @koyamashinji actually, I told that from my experience.  Puppetter is more faster but I never use it and  not so much excellent for web scraping, Thanks

Comment: and it is always better practice to use  "self.driver.close()"

Comment: Splash with scrapy  is slower than  Selenium with scrapy